# How to update mysql fields into Chinese using MyBatis

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

```
Card record=new Card();
record.setName("你好");
```

I set the name field into Chinese ,but it shows as "???" in the database.How can I config it?

OS:MAC OSX 10.8
DAtabase:MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:<portnumber>/<dbname>?characterEncoding=utf8
```

In JDBC connection string

Comment: I figured it out...it's due to the default encoding of Mysql-lantin1...I changed it and it works well now..thanks all the same