# how to update N data into oracle from mybatis

Tags: sql, oracle, mybatis, nclob

I am trying to insert/update NCLOB data on oracle using mybatis. But having problem with this.

Data type of column is `NCLOB` and below is the code i used on sqldeveloper to test it.

```
UPDATE CONTENT_TABLE SET HTML_DATA = N'通过信息通信系统的整合' WHERE SEQ = 1;
```

I tried this on sqldeveloper to test it and it works fine.(I put `'N'` in front of inserting string for NCLOB. 
But when i try it by mybatis it does not work...
here is the code i tried on mybatis.

```
UPDATE CONTENT_TABLE SET HTML_DATA = N#{htmlData} WHERE SEQ = 1
```

That didn't work. Is there any way to use that `'N'` to put on NCLOB data in mybatis other ways? 
(by the way, the reason i used NCLOB data type is to put chinese data on DB.. otherwise when data type was just CLOB, the chinese data that i insert was broken..

Comment: Have you tried setting the characterEncoding as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079525/how-to-update-mysql-fields-into-chinese-using-mybatis ? (that question is for MySQL, but this might work for Oracle, as well)

Comment: @FrankSchmitt i tried it but it gives CannotGetJdbcConnectionException... i guess i need to know the way insert by using that 'N' before the data...by the way, thanks :)

Comment: Not sure, about mybatis, but maybe there is something in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698405/how-to-insert-unicode-to-oracle-nvarchar-using-mybatis-with-spring-integration

Comment: @SudiptaMondal ok, i will try it and reply the answer thx

Comment: @SudiptaMondal i dont understand where to place the code provied on link...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mybatis text literal n without Tomcat parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75878235/mybatis-text-literal-n-without-tomcat-parameters)